# NavBackStackEntry cannot be cast to androidx.activity.ComponentActivity

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation

I have a SystemBackButtonHandler which handles back press, but I have the following error in Logcat

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry cannot be cast to androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
```

I only understand that NavBackStackEntry cannot be cast to ComponentActivity, but I don't understand how to resolve it.

```
at com.example.bettehomes.navigation.SystemBackButtonHandlerKt.SystemBackButtonHandler(SystemBackButtonHandler.kt:48)
                                                                                                        at com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.LoginScreenKt.LoginScreen(LoginScreen.kt:104)
                                                                                                        at com.example.bettehomes.navigation.NavHostKt$AppNavigation$2$3.invoke(NavHost.kt:49)
                                                                                                        at com.example.bettehomes.navigation.NavHostKt$AppNavigation$2$3.invoke(NavHost.kt:48)

                                                                                                        
@Composable
internal fun SystemBackButtonHandler(onBackPressed: () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalBackPressedDispatcher provides LocalLifecycleOwner.current as ComponentActivity
    ) {
        ComposableHandler {
            onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```